Loading reference in EF sets property to null
I have an EF class along the following, that declares a one-to-zero-or-one relationship between instances of Work.
// Work.cs
public partial class Work
{
    public string TriggerId { get; set; }
    public Work Trigger { get; set; }
}

// MyContext.cs
// ...
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Work>(e =>
        {
          e.HasOne(d => d.Trigger)
              .WithOne()
              .HasForeignKey<Work>(d => d.TriggerId);
// ...

When I try to load this relationship, the value of the foreign key is set to null:
MyWork = DbContext.Work.First(x => x.WorkId == long.Parse(WorkId));
// MyWork.TriggerId = 1
DbContext.Entry(MyWork ).Reference(x => x.Trigger).Load();
// MyWork.TriggerId = null

Why does loading the relation set the foreign key to null? Is there a reason for this that I'm missing, and is there a way to prevent this?

Why don't you just use Include ? If you intend to read the related entity immediately, why do that in two queries? That just creates delays

Also, what are the actual classes, properties and tables? You mention that TriggerID is 1 but the class you posted contains public string TriggerId { get; set; }.

I would break Triggers into a separate table.  The problem is likely a coin toss in EF. In a Relation WorkA -> WorkB Where WorkB is the "Trigger" to WorkA, Since both are type Work, When you say .HasForeignkey<Work>(x => x.TriggerId) Do you mean WorkA.TriggerId or WorkB.TriggerId? The field exists on both records as both are type "Work".
With separate tables TriggerId where you have WorkA -> TriggerB The TriggerId exists on "Work" (WorkA) or a WorkId exists on "Trigger" (TriggerB). There is no ambiguity.
